# php routing parameter like laravel

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes, url-routing, laravel-routing

My routes like this

```
$route->add("/test/foo", "xxx@yyy");
```

and add func like this - works great

```
    public function add($url, $method = null){
     $this->_uri[] = "/" . trim($url, "/");

     if ($method != null){
        $this->_method[] = $method;
     }
    }
```

and

```
public function submit(){
    foreach ($this->_uri as $uriKey => $uriValue) {

        if (preg_match("#^$uriValue$#", $getUrl)){
                $findMethod = $this->_method[$uriKey];

                $call = explode("@", $findMethod);

                if(file_exists("App/Controller/". strtolower($call[0]) .".php"))
                {
                    include PATH . "App/Controller/" . strtolower($call[0]) . ".php";
                }

                $method = new $call[0];
                $function_name = $call[1];

                call_user_func_array([$method, $function_name], $this->_params);
         }
    }
}
```

now I want to sen parametres like this

```
$route->add("/test/foo/{id}", "xxx@yyy");
```

how can i like that.

> test/foo/12

I want to send that values to  *$this->_params*

Comment: You're creating your own?  Laravel uses Symfony's routing, I would recommend you do to if you like that.  http://symfony.com/components/Routing

Comment: just i want to add that routing  system my basic mvc structure thats it?

Comment: It's a separate component, you can add it to your own framework.  That's why so many different systems using Symfony components but not the Symfony framework.

Comment: I understand. same time i wondering how can i basicly

Comment: I think it's too broad to be covered in a single SO question, try something first, look at Symfony's source for examples (it is open source), then come here for questions.